# Show tables using entity framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am trying to show all the data of `t1` table in a gridview using Entity Framework but I am getting an error

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 ToInt32(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

This is my code:

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var v = (from obj in de.t1
             where obj.Id == Convert.ToInt32(TextBox5.Text)
             select obj).ToList();
    GridView1.DataSource = v;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Maybe read the error message and try to overcome it. It clearly says that using the method ToInt32 isnt allowed so dont use it inside the query convert the string to int outside of the linq...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entity Framework is trying to execute `Convert.ToInt32(TextBox5.Text)` on the SQL side, which it obviously cannot do.
So, introduce a temporary variable to store the result of conversion:

```
var tempId = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox5.Text);
```

Then pass it to the `where` clause:

```
...
where obj.Id == tempId
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var id = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox5.Text);
            var v = (from obj in de.t1
                    where obj.Id == id
                    select obj).ToList();
            GridView1.DataSource = v;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are running into is the fact that the entity framework doesn't know how to translate `Convert.ToInt32` into a valid SQL expression.  Simply cast the textbox value to an integer before you query, and things should be fine.

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox5.Text);
    var v = (from obj in de.t1
             where obj.Id == id
             select obj).ToList();
    GridView1.DataSource = v;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var objId = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox5.Text);
    var v = (from obj in de.t1
            where obj.Id == objId
            select obj).ToList();
    GridView1.DataSource = v;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Code only answers, which may well be a workable solution, are usually improved by some explanation. Please consider commenting or explaining how your suggested code works.